# How do I redirect std input from a file to a shell script that prompts for input sayy twice?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Suppose there is a simple shell script that adds two numbers num1 and num2 after reading them from std input i.e. the keyboard. How do I get the script to take input from a file that has two numbers already stored in it?

Comment: You just redirect the file into the script: `./my_script.sh < data.txt`. Did you try that and have some problem with it? If so, please provide specifics by showing a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @kaylum thank you! It worked. Could you please direct me to the sources that directly discuss this example of std input redirection? I read a few articles and none of them discussed much about input redirection.

Comment: As usual, best check the relevant manual. In this case the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Without sample code and data, your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su] . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.